# Is it possible to make the chrome snippet auto run?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have created some javascript code which searches the DOM and exposes some information for myself in the console, but in order this to work every time I have to go to Sources part of the console, go to the snippets part, click on the snippet name and run it.

Is there a way to make it autorun? Thanks!

Comment: You can bookmark a javascript url (called a bookmarklet, normally). That might be easier.

Answer (score 4):

idk, been using "Custom JavaScript for websites" chrome extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija

Comment: Doesn't seem to function on 75.0.3770.100, also doesn't seem to allow me to access window.

Comment: Another extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptautorunner/gpgjofmpmjjopcogjgdldidobhmjmdbm

Answer (score 3):

nov 2019 : These are current Chrome Extensions that can run scripts on any page you want

- [Custom JavaScript for Websites 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/ddbjnfjiigjmcpcpkmhogomapikjbjdk) regular updates, very easy to use
- [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) regular updates and Canary versions, loads of options thus less easy UX

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, currently, this is not possible. If you want to auto-run javascript on websites I recommend using something like Tampermonkey chrome extension. It allows you to inject your client's webpage with javascript that automatically runs.

Answer (score 1):

I use Chrome feature "Event Listener Breakpoint > Script > Script First Statement" that places breakpoint before first line of each script.

I check it on ten reload the page and before first script execution the Chrome pauses. I run all the snippets and code I need then I remove the breakpoint and resume the page load.